# Using Netgear WNA3100M on ubuntu 20.04 (no Ethernet)

Tags: networking, wireless, netgear, beagleboard

I am using this newly purchased Netgear WiFi USB Dongle

lsusb gives me :
**`Bus 001 Device 005:ID 0846:9021 Netgear, Inc. WNA3100M(v1)  Wireless-N 300 [Realtek RTL8192CU]`**

ifconfig -a
**`gives wlxc4041577.... instead of wlan0`**

I think the USB dongle is detected but how to proceed further from  here to get it working?
I have no Ethernet connection. I am on Beagleboneblack btw

lsmod | grep rtl gives the below  output

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's working so far. Do you see networks when you click the Network Manager icon? What about: `nmcli device wifi list`? May we see: `lsmod | grep rtl`

Comment: nmcli : command not found

Comment: lsmod | grep rtl gives the attached output

Comment: Beagleboneblack? So not really Ubuntu? I am voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: irrespective of the hardware , underlying distribution is Ubuntu only.Request no tto close.

Answer (score 0):

OK I followed this and able to connect to the wifi network

http://beagleboard.org/static/librobotcontrol/networking_wifi.html